How to install and enable sqlsrv extensions on PHP 8.1 Xampp Ubuntu 24.04
Anyone help me install and activate the sqlsrv and sqlsrv pdo extension in PHP 8.1 in Xampp in Ubuntu 24.04?

What did you try, and which errors do you get?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
